# What's the difference between "intent", "intention" and "purpose"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

As a noun, all three have the same meaning. What is the difference, especially between *intent* and *intention*?

Comment: Have you checked their meanings in the dictionary? What do you find confusing?

Comment: *Purpose*, dating from 1250-1300 AD is, by a slim margin, the elder of *intention* (1300-1350 AD) and so should probably be deferred to in polite company. ;-)

Comment: _As a noun, they both have the same meaning_. I think you've sort of answered your own question.  @Jim: _Purpose_ is the elder of _intention_, and _necessity_ is the mother of _invention_... sounds like the start of an Ogden Nash poem.

Answer (score 1):

The usage note on [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/intention) tells me

> **purpose** what somebody is trying to achieve. Your purpose for doing something is your reason for doing it.
>
> **intention** what you intend to do, especially in the near future.

And [intent](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/intent_2) is synonymous to intention, but more formal or used in law terms.

Examples:

> Our campaign's main purpose is to raise money.
>
> He left England with the intention of travelling in Africa.
>
> She denies possessing the drug with intent to supply.

Comment: Does it  mean  that the purpose  accents the result, and the intention accents the progress

Comment: @Samuel Mainly it just differentiate the kind of goal/objective. *Purpose* defines the long-term goal, the way you go may not be clear right now but what you like to achieve. You maybe will change your strategy in future. E.g. you establish a company. *intention*, on the contrary, is more specific to your mind. You want to achieve particular aims, e.g. having a new job, traveling around the world, ... In both cases you take specific actions. The progress for *intentions* should be higher than for *purpose*. You want to travel now, but your company should continuously growing over years.